# Can Nexus/Artifactory cache RPM and NPM?

Tags: repository, npm, rpm, nexus, artifactory

We are evaluating Nexus vs Artifactory as the artifact store solution. They can cache remote Maven repositories pretty well. Can either of them cache RPM packages and NPM modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While both of them have support for hosted yum repositories for rpm packages I think neither of them supports proxying other repositories.

It is however a feature request that I have seen before for Nexus. Yum repositories on Nexus can be wrapped around a Maven repo though so you can have a Maven repo with rpm packages proxied and then exposed as a yum repo.

NPM is very different package format (using an internal database) and has been requested by users of Nexus. You could even implement support for it yourself in the shape of a Nexus plugin. The YUM support for Nexus was originally created as a community contribution.

**Update:** NPM support is available as part of Nexus Open Source and Professional since the release of 2.10. More details are in the [blog post about it](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2014/10/07/npm-registry-support-for-all/) and the [documentation is available as well](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm.html).

Comment: @zihaoyu ... NPM support has been in Nexus for a while now. Check it out!

Answer (score 11):

Support for private on-premise NPM registry was just added to Artifactory in version 3.2.0
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories

Answer (score 6):

Nexus (2.10 and later) can proxy NPM:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.10/reference/npm.html

However, there is a problem in that 2nd, 3rd level dependencies ignore the "registry" config setting, and proceed to download from the default registry at https://registry.npmjs.org.  this is a problem with NPM, rather than Nexus.

Comment: Any chance you've found a way around npm ignoring the "registry" config setting for dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Artifactory has a [superb RPM support](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories).
NPM is [in the pipe](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5930).

Comment: Please note that Artifactory RPM support is fully platform independent (it doesn't use native yum implementation, but reimplemented it in Java)

Comment: Any time estimate on NPM support?

Comment: Currently we can't commit to any release dates. Please follow the JIRA issue, it will be updated as soon as we'll determine the implementation version.

Comment: Thanks. My original question was really about caching YUM and NPM packages, like the way Maven artifacts are cached. I haven't seen any documentation about that, so I don't think it is supported. Correct?

Comment: It is very much supported for YUM.
The YUM remote repositories (as described in the docs) are exactly what you look for.

Answer (score 0):

With latest version 3.5.3 artifactory pro now officially supports YUM remote repositories (just tried it).

Be aware though that you can only mirror/proxy complete repos: exclusions/inclusions as well as virtual repos do not work since the metadata of the remote repos is not recalculated.

Comment: Since version 4.12 Artifactory now supports virtual yum repositories.